# React hooks not set state at first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem with hooks.

i'm using react-hooks, i have a button which at onClick getting data from api and setState with it.

Problem is:

when i click to button first time i get response from api but can't set it to state. When click to button second time i can setState. Why it happened ?

here is my component look like:

```
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(null);


  const fetchData = () => {
    let data = {
        id: 1
    }


    axios.post(baseUrl, data)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        setA(res.data)
      }
      console.log(a)
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchData}></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i tried to using fetchData function like that:

```
 function fetchData() {
        let data = {
            id: 1
        }


        axios.post(baseUrl, data)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.data) {
            setA(res.data)
          }
          console.log(a)
        })

      }
```

but it's not helped too

Comment: @user3348410, you should use useEfect hook for fetching, because you work with an Asynchronous call.

Comment: how it will be @Asking

Comment: `setA()` doesn't change `a` in that scope, but the fetch _does_ work the first time.

Comment: @AtulKumar that's the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), not [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema). Axios doesn't have a `json()` async method.

Comment: can you give me some example for my situation ?  useEffect is like componentDidMount not? i don't wan't fetch something in componentDidmount i wan't fetch data when user click to button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: @skyboyer no it's not

Comment: so why you do you put `console.log(a)` right next line after `setA(...)` then?

Comment: @skyboyer it won't work setA is an async

Answer (score 4):

`a` is a const. It's impossible to change it, so there's no way your console.log statement at the end of fetchData could ever log out something different than the value that `a` had when fetchData was created.

So that's not what `setA` does. The point of `setA` isn't to change the value of the const, but to cause the component to rerender. On that new render, a new set of variables will be created, and the new `a` will get the new value. Move your console.log out to the body of your component, and you'll see it rerender with the new value.

In short: Your code appears to be already working, you just have the wrong logging.

Answer (score 0):

If your scope is to fetch data, use this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState("");
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'here will be your api',
    );
    setData(result.data);
  });
```

Now your response will be stored in `data` variable.

Comment: useEffect will work on componentDidMount i think, not? i wan't it will be work at onClick

Answer (score 0):

I would not use an effect for it, effects are useful if the props or state changes and can thereby substitute lifecycle methods like componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, componentWillUnmount, etc.. But in your case these props haven't changed yet (you want to change your state though). Btw, be aware that @Asking's approach will fetch data on EVERY rerender (props or state change). If you want to use useEffect, be sure to add the second parameter to tell React when to update.

Normally, your code should work, I haven't tested but looks legit. Have you used developer tools for react to check if the state/hook has changed? Because if you say it did not work because of the `console.log` printing: Have in mind that `setA()` is an async function. The state was most likely not yet changed when you try to print it. If you haven't react developer tools (which I highly recommend) you can check the real state by adding this code in the function:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(a), [a]);
```

I have a few real improvements to your code though:

```
    function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(null);


  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    let data = {
        id: 1
    }


    const res = await axios.post(baseUrl, data);
    setA(res.data);

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchData}></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

By adding `useCallback` you ensure that the function is memorized and not declared again and again on every rerender.

Comment: Sorry but it's not changed anything :/

Comment: ups. sorry, it's worked !!! thank you so much that time i need to use useCallBack for every api request right?

Comment: You don't need useCallback actually, it is just a performance improvement & best practice. When using useCallback, it is needed to declare dependent parameters, so the function gets re-declared if they change. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Answer (score 0):

@Nicholas Tower has already answered your question.  But if you are looking for code

```
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(null);


  const fetchData = () => {
    let data = {
        id: 1
    }


    axios.post(baseUrl, data)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        setA(res.data)
      }

    })

  }


  console.log(a)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchData}></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

just place log before `return (`.  This should do

Comment: Actually i understood something that my entrie code worked well to but when i make conditions in return so like {a.length ? (<p>{a}</p>) : null} . it's not working.

Comment: before getting the length of a.  You should check if a is null like this { a && (<p>{a}</p>) }.  if you use your code {a.length ? (<p>{a}</p>) : null} you will get error because is a is null for the first time and you are trying to get the length of null which will throw error

Comment: I saw it and first state i set like   const [a, setA] = useState([]); but this case not worked too. here eg. i have length it's 0

Comment: sorry my mistake i maked it like const [a, setA] = useState(null); and my condition is   { a != null (<p>{a}</p>) }. then it's worked well

Comment: great.  Reason why  [a, setA] = useState([]) didn't worked is a.length resolve to 0 and 0 is actually false inside conditions